# Flutter : New error after dart migrate and null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

After running dart migrate I got a ton of errors, most of them I believe I have fixed, but the last one does not make sense to me.

```
 Stream<UserData> get user{
return _auth.authStateChanges()
    .asyncMap(_userFromFireBaseUser as FutureOr<UserData> Function(User?));

}
```

The problematic part is the `.asyncMap`... The part "`as FutureOr<UserData> Function(User?));`" Was added by the dart migrate.

The errors I am getting are

> error: Undefined class 'FutureOr'. (undefined_class) and error: The
> argument type 'dynamic Function(User?)' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'FutureOr Function(User?)'.

Posting rest of the code as well, it is used for Authentication.

```
  class AuthService extends ChangeNotifier
  {

 // UserData _currentUser = AuthService();
  String? _uid;
  String? _email;

  String? get getUid => _uid;
  String? get getEmail => _email;


  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //Create user ojb based on firebaseuser

  UserData? _userFromFireBaseUser(User? user) {
    return user != null ? UserData(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  
  Stream<UserData> get user{
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
        .asyncMap(_userFromFireBaseUser as FutureOr<UserData> Function(User?));

  }

  //Get UID
  Future getCurrentUID() async
  {
    final currentUid = await _auth.currentUser!.uid;
    return currentUid;
  }

  //Sign in(anon)
  Future signInAnon() async
  {
    try
    {
    UserCredential result =  await _auth.signInAnonymously();
    User? user = result.user;
    return _userFromFireBaseUser(user);
    }
    catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

What is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove type cast to `FutureOr<UserData> Function(User?)` because `_userFromFireBaseUser` is already the function that gets `User?` and returns `UserData?`. To avoid returning null values from the stream just filter them with `where`. Use this code:

```dart
Stream<UserData> get user {
  return _auth.authStateChanges()
    .asyncMap(_userFromFireBaseUser)
    .where((user) => user != null)
    .map((user) => user!);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Have to adjust to this new way...

Comment: Maybe i can help me with a follow up?
After fixing this, i now get 
type '_StreamHandlerTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, List<Todo>>' is not a subtype of type 'StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<Todo>>' in type cast

All of this appeared after dart migrate and null safety update

Comment: @s3v3ns I'm afraid I cant help without code example. Probably it would be better to post another question?

Comment: The code is .transform(Utils.transformer(Todo.fromJson) as StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<Todo>>);

Comment: I guess the problem is your transformer returns `QuerySnapshot<Object?>` but should return `QuerySnapshot<Object>` or `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` without optional generic type.

Comment: Ok, I guess i should post a new question since the problem may come from somewhere else

Comment: Also, i don't know if it caused by this change, but logging out no longer works. Can still log in, but not log out

Comment: It log outs after reloading the app, and everything seems to work, but this statement does not work anymore
if(user==null){
      return Authenticate();}
    else {